# Differentiation of the Beta function

Tags: calculus, functions, special-functions, matlab, partial-derivative

I suppose that
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[B\left(x,y\right)\right]=&\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\int_0^1t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}dt\right]\\
=&\left[\int_0^1\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}\right)dt\right]\\
=&\left[\int_0^1(x-1)t^{x-2}(1-t)^{y-1}dt\right]\\
=&(x-1)\left[B(x-1,y)\right]
\end{align*}
and computing it by Matlab Mupad results in
\begin{align*}
-\beta(x,y)\left(\Psi(x+y)-\Psi(x) \right)
\end{align*}
where $\Psi(x)$ is the digamma function. Working with digamma function is not such easy. Can anyone prove that they two are equal or mine is false?

Comment: Your differentition is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x$ is the variable of differentiation, $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[ t^x \right] \ne x t^{x-1}.$$  That is why you're getting a different result.  Instead you should have $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[ t^x \right] = t^x \log t.$$  And the extra $\log t$ is what introduces the digamma function.

Comment: Oh! You are right! A terrible mistake! since they both were variable I did this.

Comment: @hossayni: Don't forget to accept the post which satisfies you the most. Welcome here! :-)

Comment: Might i ask, which representation of the digamma function are we using here? I know the one with (1-x^n)(1-x) and x^n/1+x but not this one