# How can I get the result?

Tags: gamma-function, beta-function, digamma-function

I got a formula

$$
- \frac{ \frac {\partial B(\lambda, \xi)}{\partial \lambda}}{B(\lambda, \xi)} = - \Psi(\lambda) + \Psi(\lambda + \xi)
$$

Where $B$ is Beta function and $\Psi$ is digamma function.

How can I get the result $- \Psi(\lambda) + \Psi(\lambda + \xi)$ ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Differentiation of the Beta function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/890294/differentiation-of-the-beta-function)

Comment: @eloiPrime, Hi sir, my question is not similar to the question you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$B(x,y)=\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$$

$$\log B(x,y)=\log \Gamma(x)+\log \Gamma(y)-\log \Gamma(x+y)$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \log B(x,y)= \psi(x)-\psi(x+y)$$

That follows from the definition of digamma function.

And from the chain rule:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \log B(x,y)=\frac{1}{B(x,y)} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} B(x,y)$$

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know Beta function has a relationship formula with Gamma function.

Comment: @AlexanderYau, you are welcome. This is the most important property of Beta function